# remove unwanted contents from list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, input

The following code adds a wrong line to the list of listings

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{democodefile}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=lines]
Verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}
\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting{democodefile}%

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={LaTeX Listings}]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text ...
\chapter{Theory}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

How can I prevent this entry?

Comment: Related Question: [Hide listing from listoflistings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72864/hide-listing-from-listoflistings).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `nolol=true` option to remove that entry from the `\listoflistings`:

```
 \lstinputlisting[nolol=true]{democodefile}
```

This yields:

[image]