# Hide listing from listoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove unwanted contents from list of listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42289/remove-unwanted-contents-from-list-of-listings)

How can I hide a listing from the listoflistings, similar to using `\section*{Title}` to hide a section from the table of contents?

I want to do this in order to use a listing as an example in the preface of my thesis. As this isn't really an actual listing, I don't want it to show up in my list of listings because it doesn't really concern the content.

Comment: Use `title=Title of this listing` instead of `caption=Title of this listing`. Please, provide an example of what you're doing, if this is unclear or doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate -- see egreg's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer in the linked question doesn't really apply here, as the `nolol=true` setting will still number the listing. For an unnumbered listing one can use the keyword `title`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings

\section*{Introduction}
Here we have an unnumbered listing that won't go in the list of listings.

\begin{lstlisting}[title=Preliminary listing]
Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\section{Title}

Here we have a real listing.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Real listing]
Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]